# How to identify the part of the condition that matched in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using t-sql but I think my question is more general.

In my app, the user tries to get matching entries for a given partial name. My query tries to find a match against first name, last name and email:

```
...
WHERE FirstName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
   OR LastName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
   OR EMail LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way within the query itself to identify which part of the condition actually succeeded. Regards.

Comment: What do you want reported if it matched *multiple* conditions? I.e. say their first name forms part of their email address so searching on that name matches two columns (or 3 if their name is Steven Stevens)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 'FirstName ', ... FROM ... WHERE FirstName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
UNION 
SELECT 'LastName ', ... FROM ... WHERE LastName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
UNION 
SELECT 'EMail ', ... FROM ... WHERE EMail LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
```

Or `CASE .. WHEN`

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN FirstName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') THEN 'FirstName'
WHEN LastName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') THEN 'LastName'
WHEN EMail LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') THEN 'EMail ', *
FROM ... WHERE ...
```

UPD Delete duplicates and get all matches

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT [M] = 1, ... FROM ... WHERE FirstName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [M] = 2, ... FROM ... WHERE LastName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [M] = 4, ... FROM ... WHERE EMail LIKE ('%' + @name + '%')
),
(
    SELECT FirstName, LastName , EMail,  [SM] = SUM(M) 
    FROM x
    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName , EMail
) 
SELECT FirstName, LastName , EMail,
IIF([SM]&1<>0, 'FirstName;','') + 
IIF([SM]&2<>0, 'LastName;','') + 
IIF([SM]&4<>0, 'EMail;','') as [Match]
FROM x
```

Comment: If the search matches multiple conditions, the `UNION` one will produce multiple rows of output for the same single input row. That may or may not be correct but worth mentioning (until we find out from the OP how multiple matches *should* be dealt with).

Comment: Thx, add variant

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as;

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             ( (case when FirstName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') then 'FirstName'' else '' end) +
               (case when LastName LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') then 'LastName'' else '' end) +
               (case when Email LIKE ('%' + @name + '%') then 'Email'' else '' end)
             ) as matches         
      from t
     ) t
where matches <> '';
```

This takes into account that more than one column might match.